# How to write tdd for existing asp.net mvc application which have all business logic in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, tdd

I have an existing asp.net mvc application, where all the business logic was implemented inside controller. That is I fetch data from db to controller and write necessary business logic inside controller.

Now I am new in TDD, I know what is TDD but didn't yet implemented. So my question's are:

1. How should I use TDD approach for my application, someone suggested me to separate all business logic from controller to service layer. But I have lots of method inside controller. Should I separate all of those to methods inside service layer?
2. I read some articles there I got idea of repository pattern. Do i need to use repository pattern? or simply introduce service layer?
3. Suppose I have an action method "AddShippingAddress" what should be the probable test case, i mean some demo testing using TDD.
4. I need some good resource from where I can easily understand the TDD using existing mvc application as a beginner.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't write TDD to an existing code. That's for sure. You right unit tests for an existing code. You need to layer your application first and separate your concerns. Business layer, data layer, ...

Comment: Then does the appropriate term will be how should I unit test to existing code, and for new feature how to write TDD?

I am little confused , kindly clear me if I am wrong :)